# PostBackUrl not available on Html Buttons

Tags: asp.net, javascript, postback

We're currently performing a cross-page postback using the [`PostBackUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140.aspx) of an `asp:Button`:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" PostBackUrl="processing.aspx" />
```

which generates this javascript `onclick` stuff:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl03"
    onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions('ctl03', ', false, ', 'processing.aspx', false, false))" />
```

We would like to switch it to use a plain ol' `<button runat="server">` ([easier to style](http://particletree.com/features/rediscovering-the-button-element/)) however `PostBackUrl` is not supported on them.

So I thought: what if simply use said JavaScript in my `<button>` element?

```
<button runat="server" name="ctl03"
    onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions('ctl03', '', false, '', 'processing.aspx', false, true))">
</button>
```

And waddayaknow, it works.

Has anyone ever seen this done before? What harm will come to me or my children if I proceed with this?

Comment: Just for clarification - why are you putting the cross-page postback on the control rather than the form?  Do you have some controls that post back to the original page?

Comment: @Mark: yes, some buttons postback to the same page, one should not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question, I just looked ClientScript's [GetPostBackEventReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153110.aspx) method and here what I get :

**Button at ASP.NET page :**

```
<button id="Button2" runat="server" name="Button2"></button>
```

**At code-behind :**

```
PostBackOptions postBackOptions = new PostBackOptions(Button2);
postBackOptions.ActionUrl = "processing.aspx";
Button2.Attributes.Add("onclick", 
    ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(postBackOptions));
```

**Rendered result :**

```
<button id="Button2" name="Button2" 
    onclick="WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;Button2&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;processing.aspx&quot;, false, true))">
</button>
```

Comment: That's probably the better way of doing it.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. I've never actually used `ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference` nor realized it took options.

Answer (score 0):

"Probably not", but you're relying on implementation-details of the ASP.NET JavaScript that may change over time.

I'll be honest, I didn't actually realise there was a '<button>' HTML element.